# Django model method for saving values

Tags: python, django, django-models, architecture, loose-coupling

I'm wondering is it a good practice to have methods in Django model just for setting and saving values? For example I have a model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.save()
```

I can set name outside of model like this:

```
team.name = name
team.save()
```

Or I can use `set_name` method:

```
team.set_name(name)
```

In my understanding it is better to use `set_name` method, because it is loosely coupled. For example if I'll change name of the `name` field I won't need to update all references to this field in my codebase.

Comment: In Python it is not very common to write "setters". Usually one only does that in case the value needs *validation*, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO it's better to call save outside a method on the model because often you'll be calling `save` with more than one field changed. So if you were changing `name` and `date_last_active`, you wouldn't be using your `set_name` method.

Django generally doesn't call save on the model methods for this reason. `User.set_password()` is an example of this.

And, as others will say undoubtedly, use `save(update_fields=['field_a', 'field_b'])` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you want (if you are going to frequently change saving method)
But use [this for efficiency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save)

```
def set_name(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no technical reason for you not to do it, but I would say it is not a good practice because writing setters is entirely foreign to Python culture and therefore it will more likely be confusing then helpful to other developers.

Comment: If the function was only doing `self.attr = value` then it would be unpythonic indeed - but the goal is different here: setting the attribute AND saving the model.